# Bind map center and pushpin in windows phone 8 application

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm, bing-maps

I am developing a windows phone 8 application, i have to implement a map control with a pushpin which will show current location of the users, i am assigning current location to my pushpin, now i want this pushpin to be in the center of the map. Can anyone help me out in binding the pushpin to the center of map.

```
<maps:Map x:Name="MyMap" Center="{Binding}" ZoomLevel="15">
        <toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
            <toolkit:Pushpin x:Name="pushpin1" GeoCoordinate="{Binding}">
                <toolkit:Pushpin.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:Pushpin">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></ContentPresenter>
                            <Path Data="M0,0L1,1L2,0L2,0L1,0L0,0Z"
                              Fill="#00AAFF"
                              Stretch="Fill"
                              Margin="-2,0"
                              Height="120"
                              Width="30"
                              Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Visibility, Mode=TwoWay}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              />

                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </toolkit:Pushpin.Template>
            </toolkit:Pushpin>
        </toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
    </maps:Map>
```

Comment: Please provide your code and be more specific as to what the error is. We can't really help you unless you provide us with more details.

Comment: @Subby : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759491/pushpin-location-binding-in-windows-phone-8-app-is-not-working

Answer (score 2):

You want use Bing map in Windows Phone 8 App? I have trouble with old Bing Map control in WP8 app. I wrote about it [windows phone 8 old map vs new map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876001/windows-phone-8-old-map-vs-new-map). Best solution for WP 8 is new Nokia Map control.

In XAML:

```
 xmlns:nokiamap="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Toolkit;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

<nokiamap:Map Name="NokiaMap">
 <toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
    <toolkit:Pushpin x:Name="MyPushpin"/>
 </toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
</nokiamap:Map>
```

//Init Pushpin

```
private Pushpin MyPushpin { get; set; }

ObservableCollection<DependencyObject> children = MapExtensions.GetChildren(NokiaMap);       
    var pin = children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Pushpin)) as Pushpin;
    MyPushpin = pin;
```

// Start geolocator

```
  public void StartGeolocator()
        {
              Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
                geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
                geolocator.MovementThreshold = 10; 
                geolocator.PositionChanged += geolocator_PositionChanged;
                geolocator.StatusChanged += geolocator_StatusChanged;
            }
        }

 private void geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
       myGeoposition = new GeoCoordinate()
       {
            Latitude = args.Position.Coordinate.Latitude,
            Longitude = args.Position.Coordinate.Longitude,
       }
       MyPushpin.GeoCoordinate = myGeoposition;
       NokiaMap.SetView(myGeoposition, NokiaMap.ZoomLevel);
    }
```

See your code [Pushpin location binding in windows phone 8 app is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759491/pushpin-location-binding-in-windows-phone-8-app-is-not-working)

```
void geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        ObservableCollection<DependencyObject> children = MapExtensions.GetChildren(MyMap);       
        var pin = children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Pushpin)) as Pushpin;        
        pin.DataContext = args.Position.Coordinate;
        //witout binding 
        //pin.GeoCoordinate = args.Position.Coordinate;
    });
}
```

Comment: please provide me a better solution.

Comment: I think ObservableCollection<DependencyObject> children = MapExtensions.GetChildren(NokiaMap);       
    var pin = children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Pushpin)) as Pushpin;
    MyPushpin = pin; help in bing map too

Comment: in your code pushpin1.DataContext = args.Position.Coordinate; No, you can't use the pushpin in MapExtensions.Children in this way

Comment: can u please correct my code given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759491/pushpin-location-binding-in-windows-phone-8-app-is-not-working